# stack.yaml not created by stack new on Win7

Tags: haskell

I ran "stack new bahugs franklinchen" on a command prompt window under Win7; stack version is 1.1.2.  It did not create a stack.yaml file, and got error:

```
C:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions\sh: streamingProcess: invalid argument (Exec format error)
```

Is this likely due to a bug in template franklinchen, or something more fundamental with stack on Windows?

Am following "pragmatic Haskell" video by Alexandr Kurilin.

---

#### output

```
Downloaded lts-6.1 build plan. 
Populated index cache. 
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at github.com/commercialhas remote:
Counting objects: 24310, done. 
... Resolving deltas: 100% (6576/6576), completed with 1683 local objects. 
From github.com/commercialhaskell/all-cabal-hashes + 7a21e49...42c815c display 
-> origin/display (forced update) - [tag update] current-hackage 
-> current-hackage Fetched package index. 
C:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions\sh: streamingProcess: invalid argument (Exec format error)
```

Comment: does it work outside MSYS?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to avoid msys; I just ran it under a command prompt window.

Comment: well I had to upgrade to 1.1.2 first but on my system it runs fine - can you post more of the output (you did not start in this path right)?

Comment: Downloaded lts-6.1 build plan.
Populated index cache.
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at https://github.com/commercialhas

remote: Counting objects: 24310, done.
...
Resolving deltas: 100% (6576/6576), completed with 1683 local objects.
From https://github.com/commercialhaskell/all-cabal-hashes
 + 7a21e49...42c815c display    -> origin/display  (forced update)
 - [tag update]      current-hackage -> current-hackage
Fetched package index.
C:\msys64\usr\share\bash-completion\completions\sh: streamingProcess: invali
gument (Exec format error)

Comment: I started in directory C:Users\John\begriffs\bahugs

Comment: are you using a non-english OS?

Comment: if so try this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-system-locale#1TC=windows-7 - it helped in my case: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1448

Comment: @user3150422: Always [edit] additional information in your original post.

Comment: @Zeta I added the comment for readability - obviously my line-breaks are different

Comment: Hm. Seems like bash autocompletion in msys64 is somehow messing things up. You could disable them temporarily and try again.

Comment: Carsten: No, I'm using American English Win7.

Comment: could it be related to this:It is strongly advised to set your STACK_ROOT environment variable similarly to your root (e.g., set STACK_ROOT=c:\stack_root) before running stack. -- I don't know what to set this to ...

Comment: SUCCESS!  I used the Mingw64 shell from MSYS2 and stack init now creates a good stack.yaml